# How to make a GroundOverlay with OSMDroid?

Tags: android, overlay, osmdroid

How can i add a GroundOverlay like in Google Maps API to a OSMDroid Map?

I need to add an image as overlay for a specific bounding box.

I already tried different build-in overlays, but i didn't find the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need OSMBonusPack [GroundOverlay](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_5#18-using-groundoverlay).